# c++ template: error expected type-specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to decltype the return type by the param 'c.data()'. Could you give me some ideas.

my env: gcc4.8.5,c11.

```
template <class T>
auto data(const T& c)
  -> std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<decltype(c.data()), const char*>::type, const char*>::type {
  return c.data();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `typename` to tell the compiler that `std::enable_if<>::type` is a type:

```
template <class T>
auto data(const T& c)
  -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<decltype(c.data()), const char*>::type, const char*>::type {
  return c.data();
}
```

It's worth noting that [P0634](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) makes `typename` optional in C++20, which means your code is well-formed in C++20.